# Google drive pagination not working. Empty nextPageToken

Tags: php, symfony, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm using the Google Drive API in Symfony. The library is included with the following line in `composer.json`:

```
    "google/apiclient": "^2.2",
```

The code is the following:

```
    $service = new \Google_Service_Drive($google->getClient());

    $files = $service->files->listFiles([
        'pageSize' => 10,
        'fields'  => 'files(id, name, modifiedTime, mimeType, parents)',
        'orderBy' => 'modifiedTime desc, name'
    ]);

    $nextPageToken = $files->getNextPageToken();
```

I have around 50 files on the drive, but the `$nextPageToken` is always empty. Of course I can get all files if I set the `pageSize` to higher, but in the future we can have much more files.

I also tried to add `pageToken` and `nextPageToken` to the fields list, but then it says: "Invalid field selection pageToken" and "Invalid field selection nextPageToken".

Any ideas somone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just found the solution:

The `nextPageToken` must be added outside of the `files()` section. My mistake was that first I put it inside it, like: `files(id, name, nextPageToken)`.

This works:

```
    'fields'  => 'files(id, name, modifiedTime, mimeType, parents), nextPageToken',
```